# Strange lua push/pop behavior with the C API

Tags: c++, lua, 32-bit, powerpc, lua-api

I noticed that pushing and popping values onto/off the stack in `lua` using the [`C` API](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.html) on my target platform (`32-bit` `PowerPC` architecture) behaves very oddly. Consider the following test function:

```
void test_pushing_and_popping(lua_State *lua) {
    printf("### STARTING PUSHING/POPPING TEST ###\n");
    lua_dump_stack(lua);
    const auto value = static_cast<uint32_t>(0x206D7578);
    lua_pushinteger(lua, value);
    lua_pushnumber(lua, value);
    const auto popped_integer = lua_tointeger(lua, 1);
    const auto popped_float = lua_tonumber(lua, 2);
    printf("Popped integer: %llx\n", popped_integer);
    printf("Popped float: %f\n", popped_float);
    lua_dump_stack(lua);
    printf("Asserting equality... ");
    assert(popped_integer == popped_float);
    printf("OK!\n");
    printf("Wiping the stack...\n");
    lua_settop(lua, 0);
    lua_dump_stack(lua);
    printf("### PUSHING/POPPING TEST ENDED ###\n");
}
```

I expect this code to run successfully and that the assertion will be passed since the same value is pushed and then popped with `lua_pushinteger`, `lua_pushnumber`, `lua_tointeger` as well as `lua_tonumber` respectively.

Indeed, if I run the code on `Windows` as a `32-bit` binary, it works:

```
### STARTING PUSHING/POPPING TEST ###
Dumping the lua stack...
Stack element count: 0
Popped integer: 206d7578
Popped float: 544044408.000000
Dumping the lua stack...
Stack element count: 2
1       number  0x206D7578
2       number  0x206D7578
Asserting equality... OK!
Wiping the stack...
Dumping the lua stack...
Stack element count: 0
### PUSHING/POPPING TEST ENDED ###
```

Also on `Linux` as `64-bit` binary it works.

However, here's the output on my target platform:

```
### STARTING PUSHING/POPPING TEST ###
Dumping the lua stack...
Stack element count: 0
Popped integer: 8002b2bc00e3a9ac <-- Wrong!
Popped float: 544044416.000000   <-- Wrong!
Dumping the lua stack...
Stack element count: 2
1   number 0x80000000 <-- Wrong!
2   number 0x206d7580 <-- Wrong!
Asserting equality... <-- Crash (assertion fail)!
```

What? The first value is completely wrong and even the 2nd value is wrong. `544044416.000000` converted to hexadecimal is `0x206d7580` which is also unequal to the pushed value of `0x206D7578`. Where does the inaccuracy come from?).

I'm pretty sure I didn't corrupt anything since I ran the test right after initializing `lua`:

```
printf("Initializing lua...\n");
lua = luaL_newstate(); /* Opens Lua */
luaL_openlibs(lua); /* Opens the standard libraries */
test_pushing_and_popping(lua);
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure `popped_integer` is an `unsigned long long` and `popped_number` is a `double`? If not, you're using the wrong printf codes

Comment: Good remark, the definitions are:
`#define LUA_NUMBER float
#define LUA_INTEGER int`

Comment: So in other words `popped_integer` isn't an `unsigned long long` and `popped_number` isn't a `double`? This is why some people say to avoid `printf` and only use `cout`.

Comment: Right, I'm using `-DLUA_32BITS` since otherwise it wouldn't have compiled

Comment: Well now you know one problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial compliation error I got was worded as follows:

```
#error "Compiler does not support 'long long'. Use option '-DLUA_32BITS' \
  or '-DLUA_C89_NUMBERS' (see file 'luaconf.h' for details)"
```

It turns out I used the `-DLUA_32BITS` compilation flag which causes the data type sizes to be too small:

```
#define LUA_INTEGER int
#define LUA_NUMBER float
```

Using the largest possible is the way to go which can be accomplished with the flag: `-DLUA_C89_NUMBERS`.

This defines the data types as:

```
#define LUA_INTEGER long
#define LUA_NUMBER double
```